# How can I see websockets in console in real time without refreshing?

Tags: javascript, websocket, google-chrome-devtools

I am using chrome console to debug my html websocket application.

So when I open `WebSocket` tab and click on the request, I can see all the previous communication which happened with my application. The only problem is that I can see only **previous** communication.[image]

This means that if I will send/receive `forth message` right now, I will not be able to see it and I am forced to refresh this window (click header and back to frames or clicking on the connection one more time).

This becomes annoying when debugging real time app. Is there a way to do this without refreshing? For example I do not need to refresh anything when I am in `XHR` tab and reviewing ajax communication.

**P.S.** You can try it by yourself here: http://www.websocket.org/echo.html

Comment: Hmm I wonder if it's a "bug" with DevTools or a feature they just haven't implemented yet (seems weird that they wouldn't have it yet). What version of Chrome are you using?

Comment: I am using the current latest version 35. You can check this by yourself with whatever version you have here: http://www.websocket.org/echo.html

Comment: Nice, I was looking for somewhere to test. So yeah, I wonder if it's just a bug or unimplemented feature

Comment: Although the article is 2 years old, it seems to be on purpose, not some bug: http://blog.kaazing.com/2012/05/09/inspecting-websocket-traffic-with-chrome-developer-tools/ - so maybe the solution is request the feature. I'm still looking at other places for other references

Comment: @Ian I actually spent some time searching how to do this and saw your page. To me it seems like there is no solution so far, but I wanted to give this question a try by showing it to many people on SO. Mostly because I find it really inefficient to click around the tabs.

Comment: Yeah of course, I think that's a good idea, and definitely agree that it's really inefficient. I'm not sure there's a solution someone on SO will be able to provide to you though. I really think the solution is to request the feature directly

Comment: @Ian if nothing exists so far, I will take a look how to ask for the feature. But I noticed that a lot of things I thought do not exist actually existed and I just did not know about them. So who knows, may be I am simply missing it and somewhere there is a button or a flag "show sockets in real time" :-)

Comment: Actually, good point, I didn't think of that. It's just funny to me that it isn't real-time, because that seems to be the point of WebSockets...